# How can I update the Application Loader on MAC OS Catalina 10.15.5?

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin.forms, macos-catalina, application-loader

If i check this link https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/ this is the showed me:

[image]

But if i check my Application Loader this is showed me:

[image]

Someone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Loader has been [replaced](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036).  Use [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) instead.